# Theorem: If $x_0$ is a root of polynomial $P$ with multiplicity $m$, then it's a root of $P'$ with multiplicity of m-1, clarification needed.

Tags: polynomials, terminology, roots

So, the supposed in the theorem is that $x_0$ is a root of polynomial $P$ with multiplicity $m$. Then you can express the polynomial $P$ as $P(x)=(x-x_0)^m\cdot Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is some polynomial and is not divisible by $x-x_0$. My question is why $Q(x)$ is not divisible by $x-x_0$?

Comment: If $Q$ is divisible by $x-x_0$, the multiplicity is larger than $m$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust True, thank you :)

Comment: If $\,Q = (x\!-\!a)R\, $ then $\,P = (x\!-\!a)^{\large m}(x\!-\!a)R = (x\!-\!a)^{\large \color{#c00}{m+1}}R\,$ so root $\,a\,$ has multiplicty $\ge\color{#c00}{ m\!+\!1}\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

If it was, then we could have written $P(x) = (x-x_0)^{m+1}R(x)$ where $R(x) = \frac{Q(x)}{x-x_0}$. This would contradict root $x_0$ having multiplicity $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the meaning of the expression “$x_0$ is a root of $P(x)$ with multiplicity $m$” is that $(x-x_0)^m$ divides $P(x)$ and that furthermore $x_0$ is *not* a root of the quotient. So, if $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{(x-x_0)^m}$, then $x_0$ is not a root of $Q(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_0$ having multiplicity of exactly $m$ means that $x-x_0$ divides $P(x)$ exactly $m$ times - $Q(x)$ had a factor of $x-x_0$ then the multiplicity would be more than $m$.